# Why decouple stiff non-scalar ODEs and then use explicit RK?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm doing numerics for differential equations at the moment, and am confused about the following: I know that explicit integrators don't work for stiff ODEs, but the book used in the lecture (Numerics of Differential Equations, by Praetorius & Innerberger) states that the following would be a good idea:

Given $y'(t) = My(t)$ where M $\in R^{n \times n}$ diagonalizable with some Eigenvalues $\lambda_{i} << 0$, one can decouple the System into n scalar ODEs - this is clear and I understand everything.

Then it is proved that EXPLICIT Runge-Kutta commutes with diagonalization

Next, the book states as a conclusion, that an efficient method to solve ODEs as above is to uncouple and then use R-K for each of the resulting scalar equations.

My question is, why does this work? Shouldn't it be implicit R-K?
Or does it not matter for commutation whether the integrator is explicit/implicit and in the conclusion it should say implicit R-K-method?

Comment: You would have to chose different adapted step sizes for each of the decoupled equations. Explicit methods should all work well for $|λ_i|h_i<0.1$, their stability regions contain most of the semi-circle of radius $1$ in the negative half-plane.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann so what one wants to achieve, is the possibility of using a different step size for every component? And then I would simply use very small h for the problematic eigenvalues, small enough for explicit methods to work?

Comment: Yes, with very negative eigenvalues the component will stabilize very rapidly at zero. Then it becomes a question of balancing relative and absolute tolerances to eliminate this component from the dynamic or at least change to bigger time steps. Clustering of components and applying individual time steppings to the clusters is often done in large physical systems, for instance solar system or galactical simulations.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann ok thank you!